# Can ping and browse IP, FQDN, and hostname but can't browse via SMB to hostname of server

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2

Got a strange problem where on a server 2008 machine I am trying to browse to another server 2008's shares on a different site.

I can ping the server's ip address fine, I can ping the servername fine and I can ping the fqdn ok.

I just cant access the `\\servername`'s shares via windows explorer. I can access the shares fine via IP address.

Only way I can resolve this is by restarting the machine. It then works fine for a few days and reverts back to the same problem above.

Anyone ever had the same problem?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: **"Anyone ever had the same problem?"** -- Is that your actual question?  Because the answer is "Yes, someone has".  In all seriousness this is very difficult to answer with just the info given.  Can you access it via \\fqdn?  If so, it's a netbios issue.

Comment: Hello Thanks for the reply.

I can only access the server via the IP address from run command. When I type in  \\Servername or \\servername.domain.local it comes back with message "Windows cannot access \\servername Check spelling of the name. Otherwise there might be a problem on your network. To try to identify and resolve network problems click diagnose" it works fine after a reboot though.

Answer (score 1):

Please **DO NOT** install WINS, or enable NetBIOS over TCP/IP.  Can you please confirm whether or not you can get to the resource using **\\<FQDN>\<SHARE>**.

Also, check the remote server's firewall (if on).  Is it passing TCP 445 (SMB).  If not, allow it.

Background info: legacy NetBIOS over TCP/IP (NBT) connections use TCP port 139.  If WINS is configured, and NBT enabled, the server may try this method of communication, meaning NetBIOS name lookups come into play.  NetBIOS uses a "flat" namespace, so there is no need for any DNS domain "context".

However, if you're not using NetBIOS (and hopefully, you're not), SMB/CIFS (Server Message Blocks) is used instead.  SMB relies on proper name resolution, and therefore FQDNs come into play, or at least servers that all have common DNS domains / suffix search orders.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this issue happening a couple of times and it seams to be related to the credentials cache.
try deleting saved credentials.

Win7/server 2008 > control panel type in "Credential manager" and delete any saved credentials.

Comment: Hello Thanks for your reply.

I have checked the credential manager and it has not stored credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install WINS server feature via Server Manager roles, this can solve your problem. If problem still persists, check DNS server configuration.